Существует ли открытая лицензия между MPL, LGPL и AGPL, удовлетворяющая этим критериям?
Я ищу открытую лицензию, которая удовлетворяет следующим пяти условиям:

Копилефт: Лицензия требует, чтобы производные работы также распространялись под той же лицензией (аналогично MPL или LGPL).
Дружелюбие к зависимостям: Лицензия позволяет использовать проект как зависимость (динамическая линковка, статическая линковка, использование API и т. д.) без требования лицензировать зависимый проект под той же лицензией.
Область применения на уровне проекта: Лицензия применяет свои условия копилефта ко всему проекту, а не только к отдельным файлам (в отличие от MPL).
Отсутствие требования повторной линковки: Лицензия не требует от распространителя предоставления пользователям возможности перекомпилировать программное обеспечение с изменённой версией зависимости (в отличие от LGPL).
Использование через сеть считается распространением: Лицензия рассматривает использование через сеть (удалённое использование, программное обеспечение как услуга (SaaS)) как распространение, то есть модификации программного обеспечения должны быть доступны, если программное обеспечение становится доступным через сеть (как в AGPL).

Суммируя сказанное, я ищу лицензию, которая позволяет всем делать что угодно с библиотекой, при этом требует делиться только изменённой библиотекой. Лицензия не должна настаивать на выборе лицензии для всего, что создаётся на основе библиотеки. Лицензия также должна рассматривать использование через сеть как распространение.
Другими словами, я ищу что-то между MPL, LGPL и AGPL.
Похоже, что EPL 2.0 и CPL (из этого вопроса с opensource.stackexchange.com) удовлетворяют всем критериям, за исключением последнего, касающегося «Software as a Service».
Мой вопрос: существует ли лицензия, которая удовлетворяет всем пяти условиям, включая требование "использование через сеть считается распространением"?
Кроме того, меня интересует, может ли лицензия AGPL с "Linking Exception", "Interface Exception" или другим исключением из индекса исключений SPDX удовлетворять этим критериям.

MIT и BSD лицензии не подходят, надо понимать, поскольку не требуют распространять производный продукт под той же лицензией (т.е. они не копилефт)?

@avp да, не подходят. Нужна копилефт-лицензия.

Почему Столлман придумал копилефт я понимаю, а вам-то он зачем обязательно нужен?
